# Vue Mutation IndexOf gives -1

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi Everyone I am trying to delete a "product" the product does get deleted from the database, in my VuexStore i have a array of products so when i want to delete on i would like to splice that list, so what i have done is the following

This is the action that gets dispatched, and it is working, it does the delete

```
 removeProduct({ commit }, payload) {
    commit(REMOVE_PRODUCT)
    axios.delete(`${API_BASE}/product/${payload}`, payload).then(response => {
      console.debug('response', response.data)
      commit(REMOVE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS, response.data)
    })
```

Here is my mutation, i want to get the list of products from the store and check the index of the product where the product id is equal to the payload

```
   [REMOVE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS]: (state, payload) => {
      state.showLoader = false
  const index = state.products.findIndex(p => p.id === payload)
  state.products.splice(index, 1)
    },
```

if i console log this `state.products.indexOf(product => product.id)` i get -1

the payload is an object at the moment, but when i change that to the id of that object this `state.products.indexOf(product => product.id)` is still -1

Please help how can i get the index of the product i want to delete from the array of products and splice that product from the list

Answer (score 0):

[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) does not accept a function argument, you want to use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead.

Comment: Thanks, i have changed it, but i still get that -1, and the splice does not take of the product where the index is the same it takes it the last product off the list.

Comment: The JS debugger is your friend. Set a breakpoint and inspect the products array manually to confirm that the product you are looking for is in the array and has `id` of the same type and value as the payload. You should not splice the array if the index returned is -1 otherwise it'll remove the last element (see [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) when negative index is passed).

Comment: thanks Decade moon, my problem was that the payload was an object and i needed to get the id of that object so i changed it to payload.id now working